# File upload with Django REST Framework and coreapi

Tags: file-upload, django-rest-framework, core-api

Is it possible to perform a file upload to DRF with HyperlinkedModelSerializer in a model which has a FileField?

I am using the coreapi File class from the utils package and coreapi complains about the File object not being a JSON primative (sic).

Looking through the code it looks like the schema has to say the encoding must be multipart form.

Where can I find a working example for such a file upload to DRF into a model with a FileField?

Answer (score 5):

So... reading through [the code](https://github.com/core-api/python-client/blob/master/coreapi/client.py) I came across the `encoding` parameter for `client.action`.

If set to `multipart/form-data`, the file is correctly encoded and not validated as a JSON field but instead a body parameter.

```
with open('/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/test.png', 'rb') as f:
    client.action(schema, ['incidents', 'create'], params={ 'file': utils.File('test.png', f) }, encoding="multipart/form-data")
```

Reading through [transports/http.py](https://github.com/core-api/python-client/blob/master/coreapi/transports/http.py) and [utils.py](https://github.com/core-api/python-client/blob/master/coreapi/utils.py) for the rest of the story….

Comment: This is correct and should be selected as the answer.